# Cloned a RoR server and now getting "we're sorry, but something went wrong error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have a working RoR app that's running on Ubuntu Server, served by Nginx and Unicorn. It's using a local postgres database. I also think it's running on Sinatra instead of rails, but I'm too new to RoR to be able to say for certain.

I am attempting to create a development copy of the app to do some testing with. I'm able to do so using the source code, bundle install, and then running webbrick on my desktop. However, my developer wants to duplicate the environment that the actual production copy is running in. I cloned the server hosting the application, but when I browse to the server I get the dreaded "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error.

Here's what I've checked so for. I looked at the log files in the app/logs directory, and those haven't been updated in the last 6 days, so I suspect nothing relevant will be in them. If I run "service nginx status", it appears to be started. The database is running, and I can access it through the psql interface. Again, I'm pretty much an RoR newb... I was hoping one of you kind folks might give me some advice. Where should I look next? I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just overlooking. Thanks in advance!

Comment: An error like that should be logged somewhere. You need to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, unicorn was not starting along with NGINX. I was able to script unicorn to start on boot, and this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your config > environments > production.rb file change the consider_all_requests_local variable to true.

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```